# Ring buffer in C tail pointer issue (for audio streaming)

Tags: c, audio-streaming

I am currently writing an embedded application for audio streaming purposes. The embedded app will receive audio packets being sent over wifi, buffer the packets, then send the audio data over to a decoder chip. I have a ring buffer implementation written (with help from an excellent post here on stackoverflow), but am getting some weird behavior sometimes. In terms of audio, I am hearing some parts of the song repeat during playback. I found out that this is due to the tail pointer being set to the beginning of the buffer twice.

(In my implementation, the head pointer marks the end of valid data whereas the tail pointer marks the beginning of valid data)

For example, I see:

- Head pointer reset to start of buffer
- Tail pointer reset to start of buffer
- Tail pointer reset to start of buffer <-- this is where I hear audio repeating
- Head pointer reset to start of buffer

Here is the ring buffer implementation:

```
typedef struct ring_buffer
{
    UINT8 *buffer;      /* data buffer */
    UINT8 *buffer_end;  /* end of data buffer */
    size_t capacity;    /* maximum number of mp3Bytes in the buffer */
    size_t count;       /* number of mp3Bytes in the buffer */
    size_t typesize;    /* size of each mp3Byte in the buffer */
    UINT8 *head;        /* ring buffer head pointer */
    UINT8 *tail;        /* ring buffer tail pointer */
} ring_buffer;

PUBLIC UINT8
AppAudioStream_RingBufInit(ring_buffer *rb, size_t capacity, size_t typesize)
{   
    /* alloc buffer of size capacity * typesize */
    rb->buffer = malloc(capacity * typesize);
    if(rb->buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("ring buffer init fail\r\n");
        return RING_BUF_INIT_FAIL;
    }

    /* init rb buffer to 0 */
    memset(rb->buffer, 0, capacity * typesize);

    /* rb struct element init */
    rb->capacity = capacity;
    rb->buffer_end = rb->buffer + capacity * typesize;
    rb->count = 0;
    rb->typesize = typesize;
    rb->head = rb->buffer;
    rb->tail = rb->buffer;

    return RING_BUF_INIT_DONE;
}

PUBLIC VOID
AppAudioStream_RingBufWrite(ring_buffer *rb, UINT8 *mp3Byte)
{   
    /* default: allow overwriting if ring buffer is full */
    memcpy(rb->head, mp3Byte, rb->typesize);
    rb->head = rb->head + rb->typesize;
    if(rb->head == rb->buffer_end) {
        printf("head back to start\r\n");
        rb->head = rb->buffer;
    }

    if(rb->count == rb->capacity) {
        printf("buffer full\r\n");
        if (rb->head > rb->tail)
            rb->tail = rb->tail + rb->typesize;
    } else { 
        rb->count++;
    }
}

PUBLIC VOID
AppAudioStream_RingBufRead(ring_buffer *rb, UINT8 *mp3Byte)
{
    /* insert 'comfort noise' if the ring buffer is empty */
    if(rb->count == 0){
        printf("buffer empty\r\n");
        *mp3Byte = NOISE_BYTE;
    } else {
        /* copy data to mp3Byte and increase tail pointer */
        memcpy(mp3Byte, rb->tail, rb->typesize);
        rb->tail = rb->tail + rb->typesize;
        if(rb->tail == rb->buffer_end) {
            printf("TAIL back to start\r\n");
            printf("Tbuffer count: %i\r\n", rb->count);
            rb->tail = rb->buffer;
        }   
        rb->count--;
    }
}
```

Here is how the ring buffer write function is called:

```
while (1)
{
    AppAudioStream_BufRecv(sd, dataLen, &addr);
}

PUBLIC VOID 
AppAudioStream_BufRecv(int sd, INT32 dataLen, struct sockaddr_in *addr)
{
    INT32 addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    UINT8 j, i = 0;
    UINT8 *audioByte;

    /* listen to incoming audio data packets */
    dataLen = recvfrom(sd, (char *) appRxBuf, sizeof(appRxBuf), 0, 
                       (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);

    /* set pointer to first element in recieve buffer */
    audioByte = appRxBuf;

    /* buffer received packets into FIFO */
    while (dataLen > 0)
    {
        /* write 1 byte into audio FIFO */
        AppAudioStream_RingBufWrite(&audioFIFO, audioByte);

        /* increase pointer index and update # of bytes left to write */
        audioByte++;
        dataLen--;
    }

    /* wait until buffer is 2/3 full to start decoding */
    if (audioFIFO.count >= FIFO_TWO_THIRD_FULL 
        && audioStreamStatus == GSN_STREAM_BUFFERING) {
        audioStreamStatus = GSN_STREAM_START; 
        //printf("stream start\r\n");
    }
}
```

The ring buffer read function is called in a callback which happens every 2 ms (this is basically an ISR):

```
PRIVATE VOID 
AppAudioStream_DecoderCb(UINT32* pDummy, UINT32 TimerHandle)
{
    UINT8 spiWriteCount = 0;
    UINT8 mp3Byte;
    int i = 0;
    GSN_SPI_NUM_T spiPortNumber = GSN_SPI_NUM_0;

    /* read 32 bytes of data from FIFO and write to SPI */
    while (spiWriteCount < DATA_WRITE_AMT)
    {
        /* set stream status to decoding */
        audioStreamStatus = GSN_STREAM_DECODING;

        /* read 1 byte of audio data from FIFO */
        AppAudioStream_RingBufRead(&audioFIFO, &mp3Byte);

        /* write 1 byte of audio data out to VS1053 */
        AppSpi_SdiByteWrite(spiPortNumber, &mp3Byte);

        /* increase byte written count */
        spiWriteCount++; 
    }
}
```

Any help/insight is greatly appreciated. I am sure I am just overlooking something really obvious right now.

Thank you!

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should use the debugger to isolate a much simpler [test-case](http://sscce.org), and then come back with that.

Comment: Looks like a multi-threaded application, right? If so, you need to protect the ring buffer.

Comment: @Suma No it doesn't. Read [Code review FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: `if (rb->head > rb->tail) rb->tail = rb->tail + rb->typesize;` doesn't make a lot of sense. You need to forward the tail always, and wrap it to the beginning if it goes over the end. Otherwise your invariant `(head-tail)%capacity==count`, or whatever it is, breaks.

Comment: @Lundin I have read it and I fail to see which of the points 1-5 this question does not fulfill. 1 2 3 5 are certainly met. Is the problem with 4?

Comment: @n.m. : my reasoning for doing that is if the buffer is full (and I allow it to overwrite), then if the head pointer goes past the tail pointer, then the tail pointer would be pointing to new data, not the oldest. So in order to have the tail pointer keep pointing to the oldest data, the tail pointer must also be incremented.

Comment: @Suma "However, if your question is..." /--/ "about …" /--/ "Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets" /--/ "then your question is off-topic for this site."

Comment: It's a ring buffer. You cannot compare pointers with`>` because they wrap around.

Comment: @Lundin OK, I undestand now. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 3):

If you read to this ring buffer from a callback and write to it from elsewhere, then obviously you will get all kind of strange bugs since the ring buffer lacks protection. You need to add a mutex, semaphore, interrupt disable or whatever applies to your particular system.

Also, all variables shared between the callback and the rest of the application should be declared as volatile, to protect against dangerous optimizer bugs (*). In addition to that, such variables may need to be protected with a mutex as well to protect against race conditions.

A good way to stress test if any of the above mentioned bugs is the cause, is to create a multi-thread app. Make 10+ threads that write to the buffer, and 10+ threads that read and print from it. Log the output and see if you get odd values or garbage printed.

---

(*) (This remark has *nothing* to do with thread-safety, so please don't come posting comments about volatile not being sufficient for thread-safety, because I never said it was, and I won't have that stupid debate yet again.)

Comment: @n.m. Yes indeed, the parts about multi-threading are not applicable to a single-threaded program. Apart from that obvious statement, single-threaded programs implementing ISRs do share the very same problems as multi-threaded ones. How callbacks are handled depends on the OS, but they typically don't need any mutex guards.